# Problem when formatting a "read more" button

Tags: javascript, onclick

Newbie to HTML but 40 years total computer work, so reasonably knowledgeable about programming and great plagiarist.
Was successful working out a multiple "read more/read less" construct with
Read more instruction, but when adding a formatting code for the button with

```
<Style> .mybutton {...} </style>
```

and changing the onclick code to

```
<button class-"mybutton"" onclick="readMore('item1')" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

the "Read more button does not respond and expand the text beyond the dots. Calling the button format myBtn does not fix the problem.
Not sure why, so looking for an expert to help me with this mystery.
Thanks in advance, Gerard

Comment: Hello and Welcome to StackOverflow. Sharing the code you wrote will help solve your issue sooner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've passed the exact code, you have a mistake in your HTML `button` tag. Every attribute in a tag should start with a double quote and end with another double quote.The attribute name should be separated with the first double quote with an equal sign (and not a dash). Also, if you want to apply multiple class to a tag, you should separate them using white spaces, like this:

```
<button class="mybutton myBtn" onclick="readMore('item1')" class="myBtn">Read more</button>
```

However, you can get rid of the `myBtn` class as it's not useful in your case.

Comment: Thank you very much Nathan!

Comment: I did simplify the code and made it work after understanding how it can work and testing iteratively.

Comment: Sorry, I keep pressing return rather than completing my comments. You were really helpful! I know how much I don't know about this type of programming, but having to enhance a web site forces me to learn new tricks, which is supposedly good for an old brain. I'll have to figure out how to award you some points since I see that's a feature of  Stackoverflow.

Comment: Glad it worked. If you mistakenly add a comment by pressing the return key unintentionally, you can always edit your comment (instead of adding new ones). Also, when an answer suits your needs, you can vote on it and accept it. You can see more on the [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) page of the Stackoverflow help center.